# What is LIST method in http request?

Tags: http, curl, vault

There is a code snippet in [vault api doc](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/secret/ssh):

```
$ curl \
    --header "X-Vault-Token: ..." \
    --request LIST \
    http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/ssh/roles
```

What is `LIST` method in http request? I have never heard about this http method before.

Answer (score 1):

You've never heard of `LIST` before because it's a custom method.

curl's [`--request`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html#:%7E:text=%2DX%2C%20%2D%2Drequest%20%3Ccommand%3E) flag sets a custom request method but in name only.

> --request
>
> Specifies a custom request method to use when communicating with the HTTP server. ... Normally you don't need this option... [it] only changes the actual word used in the HTTP request...

[https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/curl.1.html#:%7E:text=%2DX%2C%20%2D%2Drequest%20%3Ccommand%3E)